# Freeing a char[] which is used as buffer for UDP based data transfer to multiple clients

Tags: c, udp

I'm developping a UDP based client - server application which has to this date 1 server and 2 clients. The 2 clients send data to the server and receive data from it. Now I'm using the following

```
static char Buffer_In[256];
static char Buffer_Out[256];
```

which I fill the to be transmitted data into:

```
memcpy( Buffer_Out, 
        (char*)&Foo_Data, 
        sizeof(Foo_Data) );
```

And send it with:

```
Ret_Value = sendto( Socket, 
                    Buffer_Out, 
                    sizeof(Buffer_Out), 
                    0, 
                    (SOCKADDR*)&Remote_Addresse, 
                    Remote_Addr_Len );
```

Foo_Data is a struct with multiple entrys. I have a second struct Baa_Data which is smaller then Foo_Data, but I use the same Buffer_Out for it. Can there be problems if I dont free the Buffer_Out first, before writing new data into into it? And if yes, what problems and how can I prevent them?

Comment: "*if I dont free the Buffer_Out*" there is nothing to "*free*".

Answer (score 1):

When `sendto()` returned the data held by the buffer had been copied. So the code is free to reuse the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

No, that will not be an issue. First of all, memory used by static variables cannot be "freed" - it's allocated at programs's startup and released only when it exits.

The portion of the code you posted looks safe (assuming you don't use multiple threads). The buffer `buffer_out` can reused immediately after `sendto` has returned; internally, this function copies the contents of buffer to some other memory location before returning.